# Unordered Sequence number generation on Identity Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a strange problem in one of my SQL Server. I have an `Identity` insert at a `seq` `id` column, where some point of time it `increased` by `2` numbers instead of `1`. My identity increment setting is one not two. What could be a problem with `Identity` column ?

Comment: Is this happening all the time or are you simply missing a value somewhere?

Comment: It's probably happening because you have failing statements that runs or transactions that gets rolled-back.

Comment: It's occurring on very few times, means rare case once in a week likewise

Comment: @DanBracuk : I'm giving message based on the max identity plus one, In logic I've assumed that next number would be incremental of last identity. But, some cases because of unordered identity sequence. I got wrong results

Comment: Stop using MAX()+1 to tell them what ID they're getting. Use SCOPE_IDENTITY() after you've inserted the value.

Comment: How does the presented information get used?  By the way, another possibility is that new records get added to your table while buddy is reading the information.

Answer (score 6):

IDENTITY values are not guaranteed to be contiguous. You could be missing numbers because of rollbacks, deletes, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE #d(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1));

INSERT #d DEFAULT VALUES;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT #d DEFAULT VALUES;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

INSERT #d DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT ID FROM #d;

DROP TABLE #d;
```

Results:

```
ID
----
1
3
```

If you need your values to be contiguous, stop using IDENTITY columns.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this kind of situations ?

Comment: @Smaug to prevent gaps? No, not with an IDENTITY column. Consider a serializable MAX() + 1 but this can still leave gaps if a row is later deleted.

Comment: There is a lot of concurrent users in my App. If i use max() + 1, it would be possibility of duplicate values. How can i sort it out this case?

Comment: @Smaug that's why you use `SERIALIZABLE`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have some uncommitted inserts so the identity for those will be counted.

Comment: How can I avoid those situations?

Comment: You should take care if occurred then use 
DBCC CHECKIDENT 
( 
        table_name
        [ , { NORESEED | { RESEED [ , new_reseed_value ] } } ]
)
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ] to reseed to specific point.